# Insert an empty space at the end of a string

Tags: scroll, marquee, banner, kbhit

I was wondering how can I insert an empty space in the string *text* (defined in 
char *text = argv[1];)

For example, if a write:

---

./mar "Hello how are you"

---

I would like to see/

---

### Hello how are you Hello how are you Hello how are you Hello how are you

and not

---

### Hello how are youHello how are youHello how are youHello how are youHello how are you

scrolling horizontally in the cli.

The code is:

```
/*mar.c*/
#include <curses.h>
#include <unistd.h> // For sleep()
#include <string.h> // For strlen()
#include <stdlib.h> // For malloc()
#include <sys/select.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

char *text = argv[1];
char *scroll;
int text_length;
int i,p, max_x, max_y;


// Get text length
text_length = strlen(text);

// Initialize screen for ncurses
initscr();

// Don't show cursor
curs_set(0);

// Clear the screen
clear();

// Get terminal dimensions
getmaxyx(stdscr, max_y, max_x);

scroll = malloc(2 * max_x + 1);

for (i=0; i< 2*max_x; i++) {
    getmaxyx(stdscr, max_y, max_x);    
    scroll[i] = text[i % text_length];
}

scroll[2*max_x - 1]='\0';


// Scroll text back across the screen
p=0;
do{
        getmaxyx(stdscr, max_y, max_x);
        mvaddnstr(0,0,&scroll[p%max_x], max_x);
        refresh();
        usleep(40000);
    p=p+1;
// Execute while none key is pressed   
}while (!kbhit());

endwin();
return 0;
}

int kbhit(void)
{
struct timeval tv;
fd_set read_fd;

tv.tv_sec=0;
tv.tv_usec=0;
FD_ZERO(&read_fd);
FD_SET(0,&read_fd);

if(select(1, &read_fd, NULL, NULL, &tv) == -1)
return 0;

if(FD_ISSET(0,&read_fd))
return 1;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate a new `char` array whose length is 2 bytes greater than the length of the argument string (so that there's room both for the space and for the null terminator). Then, call `strcpy` to copy the argument string into the new array, overwrite the second-to-last index with a space and put a null terminator into the last index.

Comment: (And, if you want to follow good coding practices, use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy` - but it shouldn't be necessary here, since we have already allocated the array to be large enough. On the other hand, you might want to set a limit on the size of the input string and to check that the memory allocation succeeds... </security_rant>)